# how to implement a "trending counter" to count words with a sliding window?

Tags: algorithm, redis, distributed-computing, word-count, sliding-window

I have multiple processes counting words. For example, I have multiple kafka consumers, consuming different partitions of a single kafka topic. Each message on the topic is a single word (string). the word is both the key and and the value for my kafka topic.
A consumer will consume a message and increase the counter for that word by 1.

I want to be able to query for the 10 most popular words in the past 5 minutes.
Once a word is no longer in the current window, I do not want to count it.
Let's assume we're using processing time as our timestamp.

What is the best way to do that?

language-agnostic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RedisBloom has a Top-K solution that might fit your use case in case your stream has a large number of different words to count.

In [this blog post](https://redislabs.com/blog/meet-top-k-awesome-probabilistic-addition-redisbloom/) (by me :) you can see Top-K is preferable to sort sets both in execution time and in memory requirements. In my benchamrk, for `k=10`, memory consumption was less than 10kb vs ~6mb for a sorted set. The dataset was the book `War and Peace` which has total of ~500,000 and about 41,000 different words.

My recommandation is to keep several Top-K keys and retire them after 5 minutes. The number of keys depends of the resolution you want.

Another nice feature of Top-K is that you get elements as they are being expelled from the Top-K list. This allow you to track trends. This feature is not available with `sort sets`.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a Redis `sorted set` for each minute, e.g. `counter:YYYYMMDDHHmm`.

#### Insert

When you get a new item, use the processing time to construct the key for the counter, and call `ZINCRBY` to increment the counter.

```
// Now it's 2019/11/19 01:14, and you get a word: `hello`
ZINCRBY counter:201911190114 1 hello

// You get another word in the same minute: `word`
ZINCRBY counter:201911190114 1 hello

// Time passed by...

// Now it's 2019/11/19 01:20, and you get a word: 'hi', insert the word in another counter
ZINCRBY counter:201911190120 1 hi
```

#### Search

If you want to query for the 10 most popular words in the past 5 minutes, calc the keys of these 5 counters by current time, and call `ZUNIONSTORE` to merge the results into a new merged result. Finally, call `ZREVRANGE` to get the top 10 members of the new sorted set.

```
// Now it's 2019/11/19 02:05, search for the last 5 minutes' counters
ZUNIONSTORE dest 5 counter:201911190204 counter:201911190203 counter:201911190202 counter:201911190201 counter:201911190200

// Get top 10 words
ZREVRANGE dest 0 9
```

Also you might need to set expiration for these counters to avoid reaching the limit of memory.

Comment: That solution should work, but if you have high throughput of text and holding all the word counters might be too much on your memory you might want to consider using instead of SortedSet a sub linear memory probabilistic solution like TopK https://oss.redislabs.com/redisbloom/TopK_Commands/